# Big O notation: Negative logarithmic argument

Tags: big-o

Is it correct to write the following equalities writen in the image:
[image]

I'm not sure about the red marked passage.

Furtheremore, I know that constants are neglected such as O(12 log b) = O(log b).
Does this means that O(log b^12) = O(log b) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O(log b<sup>12</sup>) = O(log b) is correct for the reason you state in the question.

The derivation in the image is not correct, because O(f) is an empty set whenever f is a function taking negative values for arbitrarily large inputs. You cannot therefore discard a constant *negative* factor like -12, because this changes the sign of the function; in general O(f) and O(-f) are not the same, and (at least) one of them is an empty set (unless f is identically zero beyond some bound).

Comment: @RichardBarber No.

Comment: @RichardBarber I think you are confused about some high-school algebra - `log b^12 = 12 log b`.

Comment: I am really struggling to see why you think a constant factor of 12 should somehow morph into a factor of b.